# MS-Access Error When Editing records from SQL table - [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I recently tried to run my functioning MSAccess Database on a virtual cloud based machine running Windows Server 2019. All of my save functions do not work from the PC when editing a record. They work fine to create new records in the associated SQL tables. Below is an example of one of my save functions. Loading and creating new records works fine, just editing current SQL records causes the error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

```vb
    Private Function fSave() As Boolean 'True if Saved properly False on Error
    Dim SQLConnectionString As String
    Dim SQLConnectionUserName As String
    Dim SQLConnectionPassword As String
    SQLConnectionString = Forms!frm00SystemSettings!txtSQLConnectionString
    SQLConnectionUserName = Forms!frm00SystemSettings!txtSQLConnectionUserName
    SQLConnectionPassword = Forms!frm00SystemSettings!txtSQLConnectionPassword
    
      Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
      Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
      Dim strSQL As String
        
    
      Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
      Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
        
      cnn.Open SQLConnectionString, SQLConnectionUserName, SQLConnectionPassword
      If IsNothing(Me.txtIdentifier.Value) Then
            strSQL = "SELECT * " & _
                     "FROM vwM01Commodity " & _
                     "WHERE CommodityID = Null"
      Else
            strSQL = "SELECT * " & _
                     "FROM vwM01Commodity " & _
                     "WHERE CommodityID = " & Me.txtIdentifier.Value
      End If
      rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic
      rst.Open strSQL, cnn
    
      If rst.EOF Then
        rst.AddNew
      End If
        rst.Fields("Commodity") = Me.txtCommodity.Value
        rst.Update    
          
     End Function
```

Comment: FYI, `CommodityID = Null` is never going to return any rows.

Comment: The rst.update line triggers the error, but only if I am editing a record in the vwM01Commodity view.